# Passing values from Batch to DB2

Tags: batch-file, db2

I am really new to Batch and DB2 and got little time to explore much about them. I just want to know how it is possible for a batch program to pass a value/s to a db2 file so I can manipulate my database.

I found several suggestions but none of them worked. Here's my batch codes so far:

```
Rem This is db2execute.bat

@echo off
db2cmd -c -w -i db2 -tf INSERT.db2 id=1
PAUSE
```

My .db2 file on the other hand:

```
CONNECT TO SAMPLEDB;
INSERT INTO TB1 VALUES('$(ID)');
```

I would really appreciate some kind help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the present time, in the shipping versions of Db2-LUW, the CLP (command line processor) does not directly support parameters in script files in the style that your question suggests.

If your product-type and version offers the [clpplus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/c0053823.html) command, then you can instead try using the Oracle sqlplus style for passing parameters on the command line and referencing those parameters in your script.  See the Db2 and Oracle documentation for details .

Comment: "At the present time..."   